# Highchart 3d: Chart graph. Zaxis alignment issue

Tags: highcharts, 3d, scatter-plot

I am working on a 3d scatter plot chart. But facing issues with setting up the position of z axis label. 
Kindly help me in getting it back in proper position. Thanks in advance.

[image]

I tried to play around with the zaxis values but no luck.

```
zAxis: {

  min: 0,
  max: 11,
  gridLineColor: 'white',
  categories: ['W', '1', '2', '3c', '3b', '3a', '4c', '4b', '4a', '5c', '5b', '5a'],
  labels: {
    y: 1,
    rotation: 30,
    align: 'center'
  }
}
```

JS Fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/suprcool01/xvdcqbyk/24/

Comment: I don't know what the reason is, but there is something with the zPadding. Changing it a bit gives you this: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/xvdcqbyk/25/, but it will probably not work if you add another series.

Comment: It did the job but I dont think its the actual answer. Because I have a dynamic scenario where this might change.
Anyways. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Highcharts doesn't support **z** coordinates for `column` series in 3d mode. It should be implemented like it's done in `scatter3d` series: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter3d.data.z You can propose this idea here: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api