# 3D Highcharts z-axis format

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I am trying to implement the 3D library of highcharts. I have had good success when using the `scatter` option for series, but when I try to use the `column` option I have some formatting issues.

My main problem is my dataset is very volatile, I can have any number of z-axis categories, and have varying amounts of [x,y] points in each category. The x-axis and y-axis format correctly, but the z-axis does not. It is constantly too deep or too shallow (depending on my dataset and my format parameters). Here is a fiddle of what I have so far http://jsfiddle.net/rhavelka/owyrmc7o/2/

I don't want to to have to change the `plotOptions:{ column:{ depth } }` and the `plotOptions:{ series:{ pointPadding} }` variables on the fly to fit the dataset if I don't have to.

tl;dr The highcharts z-axis doesn't format it's depth depending on dataset size. How do I fix that?

Comment: Here's a link to very similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50212841/highchart-3d-chart-graph-zaxis-alignment-issue#comment87480454_50212841 My comment is relevant in this case too: *Highcharts doesn't support z coordinates for column series in 3d mode. It should be implemented like it's done in scatter3d series: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter3d.data.z You can propose this idea here: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api*

Comment: Thank you for the resources. I will proposed it to the forum and hopefully get a response, but until then I found a work around. `chart.options3d.depth: data.length*(columnDepth + columnPadding)` where `data.length`, `columnDepth`, and `columnPadding` are all user defined variables.